# Laravel 7 - Attach Multiple Files To Mailables

Tags: laravel

How does one go about attaching multiple files to laravel 7 mailable?
error :The path cannot be empty

I've searched the docs and also various search terms here on stack to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

myController and storage the file

```
public function imageSave($filex,$destination){

        $ext=$filex->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = $filex->getClientOriginalName();
        $mainFilename =$name.'_'.time().'.'.$ext;
        $filex->move($destination, $mainFilename);

        return $mainFilename;
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this -> validertor( $request , [
        'rip' => 'required' ,
        'rip. *' => 'mimes: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg | max: 2048',
        'filep' => 'required' ,
        'filep. *' => 'mimes: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg | max: 2048',
        'fishea' => 'required' ,
        'fishea. *' => 'mimes: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg | max: 2048'
]);

        $data[] = [
            'filep' => $request->filep->getRealPath(),
            [
                'mime' => $request->filep->getClientMimeType(),
                'as' => $request->filep->getClientOriginalName()
            ],
            'rip' => $request->rip->getRealPath(),
            [
                'mime' => $request->rip->getClientMimeType(),
                'as' => $request->rip->getClientOriginalName()
            ],
            'fishea' => $request->fishea->getRealPath(),
            [
                'mime' => $request->fishea->getClientMimeType(),
                'as' => $request->fishea->getClientOriginalName()
            ],
        ];


    if ($request->hasFile('filep') && $request->hasFile('rip') && $request->hasFile('fishea')) {
        $filep = $this->imageSave($request->filep,'uploads/cin/');
        $rip = $this->imageSave($request->rip,'uploads/rip/');
        $fishea = $this->imageSave($request->fishea,'uploads/anthropo/');

        // Required validation
        $contact = new Contact();

        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->adresse = $request->adresse;
        $contact->ville = $request->ville;
        $contact->num = $request->num;


        $contact->filep = $filep;
        $contact->rip   =  $rip;
        $contact->fishea = $fishea;
     }

    $admin_email = 'contact@admin_email.com';
    Mail::to($admin_email)->send(new SendMailP($data));
    session()->flash('success', 'Thank you! ');
    $contact ->save();
    return redirect('contact');
}

private function validertor(Request $request, array $array)
{
}
```

}

when ad dd( $data[]) in SendMai

```
     public function build()
    {
dd($this->data);
        $data = $this->data;
        $mail = $this->subject('[organisation]' . " " . " Sujet «" . "»")
       ->markdown('frontend.contact.mail.contact-form', compact('data'));
        // $attachments is an array with file paths of attachments
        foreach($data as $filePath => $fileParameters){
            $mail->attach($filePath, $fileParameters);
        }
        return $mail;
    }
}
```

dd($this->data) in Build Method:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "filep" => "C:\wamp64\tmp\php71B9.tmp"
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "mime" => "image/png"
      "as" => "crm.png"
    ]
    "rip" => "C:\wamp64\tmp\php71BA.tmp"
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "mime" => "image/png"
      "as" => "logo-1.png"
    ]
    "fishea" => "C:\wamp64\tmp\php71BB.tmp"
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "mime" => "image/png"
      "as" => "smartphone-1.png"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: put your code in your question, not images. to correct anything people will have to write it down so try to make it easier for them. Also make it clear wich errors you're having, (log/error text/...)

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: `dd( $data[])` and check what you get